# kubuntu 14.04 to full screen

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu

I installed kubuntu 14.04 via VirtualBox. I tried to change the resolution via the settings, but I have only one option there: 640X480. I understood that I need to install guest additions, but when I try to do so from "Devices"->"insert guest additions CD image", I get this message: "unable to insert the virtual optical disk c..."

I also tried to use the command:
`sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
that doesn't work as well.

how can I change the resolution to full screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install  guest additions from the additional drivers

Open up a terminal and type in.

```
sudo /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4
```

it should be obvious what to do from here

[image]

```
and then reboot
```